# How do I add more than 8 channels to the VSE?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I am struggling with the audio track (it refused to save the fade in markers I’d placed). I muted the first because I wanted to use it as a guide for the new one, but didn’t realize one a transition was in Channel 6 (original audio in Channel 7, the top most I can see). It never appeared, so I moved stuff around and made room for the new audio in 6. When I pressed playback I could hear two audio tracks playing, slightly off synch. I deleted all audio tracks, but the audio still plays (out of place from where it needs to be).

I’ve spent hours watching videos, and scanning tutorials and the help guide, but can’t find anything to tell me how to view the rest of the 32 channels where I think the errant audio strip is hiding.

Answer (score 4):

In Blender 3 and above you have to drag a strip to the area of the hidden channels in order to make the visible. It's not enough to simply scroll there.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This is one of those 'hidden information' things that are hard to intuitively test out or even find from web. Especially since scrolling is not enough! Lifesaver!

Comment: @ManuJärvinen I know! Took me some time to find out too :D.

Answer (score 3):

The VSE can have a lot more than 32 strips. You will find a scroll bar to the left of the VSE that you can use to scroll up/down through the list of strips.

Use <kbd>[image: MMB] MMB</kbd> to pan around the VSE.

Use <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>[image: MMB] MMB</kbd> to scale the vse display, so that strips may be smaller/larger so that more strips can be visible at the same time.

This same control works the same in most editors.

Answer (score 2):

And after extensive reading of the manual, I tried the very simple trick of clicking the Home button to "view all sequences" and lo and behold! All of the channels being utilized and THREE additional audio files hanging out out of sight of those first 8.